# How to set IST time in Remote Machine?

Tags: go, google-app-engine

```golang
loc, err := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Calcutta") 
if err != nil{
     fmt.Println(err) 
}
now := time.Now().In(loc)
fmt.Println(now)
```

First I wanted IST time format in my remote machine,
But I got the following error, In local machine working fine.
The error comes only for Remote Machine*

I got an error:

> The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> panic: time: missing Location in a call to Time. In

Comment: from doc `In panics if loc is nil.` so `loc` may be at nil `time.Now().In(loc)`. Is  `time.LoadLocation()` returning any error and thus nil `loc`?

Comment: Looks like tzdata isn't available on the host / in the container running the program. Try importing [time/tzdata](https://pkg.go.dev/time/tzdata).

Comment: Hi Charles, do let me know if my information below helped you or are you looking for some other information.

Comment: Were you able to set the time with the suggestions below.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //IST  -> UTC + 5:30
fixedZone := time.FixedZone("IST", 5*3600+1800)
in := time.Now().In(fixedZone)
log.Println(in)
log.Println(in.Zone())

log.Println("--------------------------")
// my time is UTC+8:00
name, offset := time.Now().Zone()
log.Println(name)
log.Println(offset)

2022/08/24 17:53:35 2022-08-24 15:23:35.0625673 +0530 IST
2022/08/24 17:53:35 IST 19800
2022/08/24 17:53:35 --------------------------
2022/08/24 17:53:35 CST
2022/08/24 17:53:35 28800
```

Comment: This only works for times after 14 October 1945, and will break if Kolkata ever starts observing DST again.

Comment: I found before Oct 14th, Kolkata existed DST, 1943-1944-->UTC+5:30, 1942 from UTC+5:30 to UTC+6:30, 1941 HMT->BURT :UTC+6:30, 1940 :UTC+5:30, so maybe need deal it specific

Answer (score 0):

This generally may happen when the function time.LoadLocation() is called and it looks for a reference for the time zoneinfo and the same is not available on the Remote machine. You should check as to where you are running this program; the Remote machine also contains a valid path for the zoneinfo.zip file .
If you were using this earlier and have recently upgraded to a new version for Go,also update the zoneinfo.zip file to the latest version from the golang repository on the same remote machine as well.
I would also recommend you to check details on [Go Package](https://pkg.go.dev/time#LoadLocation) for [func LoadLocation](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/go1.19:src/time/zoneinfo.go;l=641).